# SQL - check if a value in a list does not exist in table and return boolean accordingly

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

I have a simple database schema composed of 3 tables

**User**
id
name
matricule

**Document**
id
serial

**User_Document** (join table)
user_id
document_id

I want to check if all items of list( list of Document.serial) exists in the join table(User_Document) then return true 
If at least one not exists it should return false

There is my current query

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (
SELECT *
FROM user_document ud
INNER JOIN  document d ON d.id= ud.document_id  
INNER JOIN  user u ON u.id = ud.user_id
where u.matricule='123'
and d.serial in ('#1' ,'#2' , '#3')
)
THEN TRUE 
ELSE FALSE 
END
```

This doesn't work because it will returns always true even if a single item of list doesn't exist in the join table

I am under PostgreSQL

Thank you very much

Comment: `I want to check if all items of a document serial list exists in...` Do you mean: if one element does not exist (but the others do), it should return False? Please rephrase ...

Comment: @Wildplasser . Yes that's it . Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate serials in an array and compare with an array of the desired serials:

```
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT d.serial
             FROM user_document ud
             JOIN document d ON d.id = ud.document_id  
             JOIN "user" u ON u.id = ud.user_id
             WHERE u.matricule = '123') @> ARRAY['#1', '#2', '#3']::varchar[];
```

Note that I had to quote the table name for `user` in the query, since it's a [reserved key word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html) in PostgreSQL and the SQL standard.

Another approach is to count the distinct serials matching the list and check that the count matches the length of the list:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT d.serial) = 3
FROM user_document ud
JOIN document d ON d.id= ud.document_id  
JOIN "user" u ON u.id = ud.user_id
WHERE u.matricule='123' AND d.serial IN ('#1','#2','#3');
```

This version also works with databases that do not support arrays (such as MySQL), and might be more efficient if there is a large number of documents related to the user.

Comment: Thank you but i got a " operator does not exist: character varying[] @> text[] . No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. " :(

Comment: Added cast to `varchar[]`, please retry. Could you please update your question with the full DDL for your schema, including the types of each column?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
D.*,
(CASE WHEN (SELECT 1 FROM USER_DOCUMENT 
WHERE D.ID = UD.DOCUMENT_ID LIMIT 1) = 1 THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END)
FROM DOCUMENT D
```

Comment: I need to compare from a existing document serial list not all entries in document. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
     SELECT bool_and(ud.document_id is not null) as all_match,
            bool_or(ud.documnet_id is not null) as at_least_one_matches
       FROM document d
  LEFT JOIN user_document ud ON d.id = ud.document_id;
```

This should go through, do a left join, and return true if *all* match, and false if *one* mismatches.  The second returns true if at least one matches.

If you want to sho

Comment: This is almost the result I want except I want to filter through a defined list of document id and not the entire table (as shown in my example)
thank you very much

Comment: Then add a where clause.  The aggregations work on rows which are not excluded by the where clause.